# Change volume using mouse scroll wheel over taskbar with multiple monitors

Tags: autohotkey

I use the AutoHotkey script below which allows me to change the volume using my mouse scroll wheel when hovering over the taskbar in Windows 10. However, this only works on the monitor that is selected as the "main display". I have multiple displays that are used to extend my desktop. Using the mouse wheel scroll on the extended monitors taskbars does not work.

Is there a way to modify the script to work with extended displays?

```
SendMode Input ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

;--------------------------------------------------------------------
; Change volume using mouse scroll wheel over taskbar
;--------------------------------------------------------------------

#if MouseIsOver("ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd")

WheelUp::
Send {Volume_Up}
return

WheelDown::
Send {Volume_Down}
return

MouseIsOver(WinTitle) {
    MouseGetPos,,, Win
    return WinExist(WinTitle . " ahk_id " . Win)
}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with AutoHotKey scripts, and [the documentation for `#if` is unclear](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm) about when the scope of the `#if` ends (unlike `if` (without `#`) [which ends at `}`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfEqual.htm)) - can you repost your script to use `if` instead of `#if`?

Comment: @Dai The #if statement in AutoHotKey is explained [here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm).

Comment: Indeed, I've updated my comment-reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the "Main display"'s desktop's taskbar has the Window class `Shell_TrayWnd`.

Secondary taskbars have the Window class `Shell_SecondaryTrayWnd`.

I'm not familiar with AutoHotKey's scripts' syntax - so I can't give you an answer you can copy+paste - but you need to change the logical-condition in the `If` statement to check for `MouseIsOver("ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd") **OR** MouseIsOver("ahk_class Shell_SecondaryTrayWnd")`.

Comment: Thanks! Changing the if statement to the following worked: `#if MouseIsOver("ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd") || MouseIsOver("ahk_class Shell_SecondaryTrayWnd")`

Comment: @RyanBuening I’m useful!